# xampp Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, xampp, undefined, offset, notice

Can anyone help me with this error? When running the site on my host i get no errors but when i run it with xampp on my pc i get this

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp1\htdocs\ctcoun1kk\countrycheck.php on line 273

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp1\htdocs\ctcoun1kk\countrycheck.php on line 273

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp1\htdocs\ctcoun1kk\countrycheck.php on line 273

Line 273 is this one->

```
$decip = ($numbers[0]*16777216)+($numbers[1]*65536)+($numbers[2]*256)+($numbers[3]);

function x_dot2dec($dotip) { 
    $numbers = preg_split( "/./", $dotip); 
    $decip = ($numbers[0]*16777216)+($numbers[1]*65536)+($numbers[2]*256)+($numbers[3]); 
    return array ($decip, $numbers[0]); 
}
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: The $numbers variable is not initialized, it needs to be declared before you can use it. For example `$numbers = '';` somewhere above the `$decip = ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those are just notices. The script should work fine if you ignore thos. Set error reporting level using error_reporting (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and those will go away. This is set on your other server- that's why you don't see these "errors".

```
error_reporting(0); //disable all errors and notices
```

Comment: It's not the best solution to disable warnings. In fact all should be turned on when you develop application and all should be eliminated. If one of values is not set like in this example what's the point to make any calculation?

Comment: Turning off error reporting worked but do you think the script will still work ok? I don't realy get why there is a error if the script will still run ok.

Comment: To stop the Errors i turned off display_errors=Off in the php.ini file. Thank you all for your help :) I just hope the script will run normal with them errors.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $numbers variable is not set properly. Before 273 line put:

```
var_dump($numbers);
```

and check if indexes 0,1,2 and 3 are set

Comment: Hi :) I am sort of new to this, The line before *273* is this     $numbers = preg_split( "/\./", $dotip); and could you tell me how to check indexes? :P

Comment: Look at 1st example at http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php - you have there var_dump of array and have 0 => "sth", 1 => "sth2", ...". In your var_dump output you should also have 0,1,2,3